# How to clear PHP $_SESSION by apache?

Tags: php, apache, session

I restarted apache,but the session doesn't expire!

Answer (score 16):

Delete all files in the temporary directory defined in php.ini.

Comment: I believe deleting the files manually would be a solution if you need to kill all sessions at once. But I hope this is a once-in-forever situation.

Comment: this would destroy sessions of all users.

Comment: In case if you don't know where those files are located, look for the "session.save_path" value in your phpinfo. For me it was `/var/lib/php/session`

Answer (score 8):

Why not use `session_destroy()` to destroy the client's session?

Comment: That, and you could set the time-limit to minus 3600 or something.

Comment: It will only destroy session of a specific user,but I want to destroy all!

Comment: I want to destroy sessions of all users.

Answer (score 5):

If you have:

```
session.save_handler = files
```

in your php.ini file, which I believe you will by default, then session data will be stored in files. Therefore bouncing the server won't destroy them.

Answer (score 4):

What I ussually do when I'm developing, I create a page that unsets and destroys all sessions. So everytime I need to destoy the sessions I run the script. eg. www.example.com/destroySession.php

destroySession.php contains something like (only an example)

```
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['name']); //If only one session variable is used
session_destroy();
```